# How to export Windows Event log for a specific source with WMI?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, event-log

I'm trying to use [`Win32_NTEventLogFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394225(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class to export the `Applications` branch of the Windows Event log, but filter it only for a specific source. (Otherwise the log contains too much unnecessary information.)

So, just as an example, say, I need to export all records that contain `MSSQL$SQLSRVR2012`:

[image]

I do this:

```
using System.Management;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BackupEventLogFilterBySource("Application", "MSSQL$SQLSRVR2012", @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\exp.evtx");
    }


    public static void BackupEventLogFilterBySource(String logName, String applicationName, String targetFile)
    {
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\cimv2");
        scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        scope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
            String.Format("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile Where LogFileName='{0}' And Sources='{1}'",
                logName, applicationName)
        );

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher search = 
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject o in search.Get())
            {
                ManagementBaseObject inParams = o.GetMethodParameters("BackupEventlog");
                inParams["ArchiveFileName"] = targetFile;
                ManagementBaseObject outParams = o.InvokeMethod("BackupEventLog", inParams, null);
                var res = outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value;

                Console.Write("result=" + res + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

But that query fails with the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.ManagementException'
>   occurred in System.Management.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid query

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not sure but, if you got through this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394225(v=vs.85).aspx It says `Sources` is an array of string type

Comment: @FaizanRabbani: Yeah, I saw it too. Although I'm not sure what that means? It doesn't really make sense for it to be an array.

Comment: It is for multiple Sources, but I don't know how to put it in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal name used to identify the `Source` may be different from what is presented in the Computer Management UI.
For example, the Source `Winlogon`, internally is referenced as `Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon`.

Also, there's a problem with the `Sources` parameter, since it's an array.

This modified method uses `Win32_NTLogEvent` instead of `Win32_NTEventLogFile`.
I think it goes more directly to the target.
The query uses `LIKE '%parameter%'` to filter the Source, for the reason I mentioned. It's however possible to extract all the sources names using your original method with the `LogFileName` filter and analyse the content of the `Sources { }` array.

---

The values extracted from the Log Source File are store in a List.
You can use it's properties to create a report that looks like the one you see in  Event Viewer.

> **Note:** The `TimeGenerated` and `TimeLogged` properties can be converted  to `DateTime` using the [ManagementDateTimeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter)
>   [.ToDateTime Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.todatetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class WinLogEvent
{
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    public string LogName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public UInt16 EventCode { get; set; }
    public uint EventIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public uint RecordNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeGenerated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeLogged { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public string[] InsertionStrings { get; set; }
}

private static EnumerationOptions GetEnumerationOptions(bool deepScan)
{
    var mOptions = new EnumerationOptions()
    {
        Rewindable = false,        //Forward only query => no caching
        ReturnImmediately = true,  //Pseudo-async result
        DirectRead = true,
        EnumerateDeep = deepScan
    };
    return mOptions;
}

private static ConnectionOptions GetConnectionOptions(string UserName, string Password, string Domain)
{
    var connOptions = new ConnectionOptions()
    {
        EnablePrivileges = true,
        Timeout = ManagementOptions.InfiniteTimeout,
        Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
        Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Default,
        Username = UserName,
        Password = Password,
        //Authority = "NTLMDOMAIN:[domain]"
        Authority = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Domain) ? $"NTLMDOMAIN:{Domain}" : string.Empty
    };
    return connOptions;
}

public static List<WinLogEvent> BackupEventLogFilterBySource(string logName, string sourceName)
{
    List<WinLogEvent> logEvents = new List<WinLogEvent>();

    var connOptions = GetConnectionOptions(null, null, null);
    var options = GetEnumerationOptions(false);
    var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\CIMV2", connOptions);
    scope.Connect();

    var query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent");
    query.Condition = $"Logfile='{logName}' AND SourceName LIKE '%{sourceName}%'";

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query, options))
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject eventLog in moSearch.Get())
        {
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = eventLog.GetMethodParameters("BackupEventlog");
            inParams["ArchiveFileName"] = @"D:\exp.evtx";
            ManagementBaseObject outParams = eventLog.InvokeMethod("BackupEventLog", inParams, null);
            var res = outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value;

            logEvents.Add(new WinLogEvent
            {
                ComputerName = eventLog.GetPropertyValue("ComputerName")?.ToString(),
                LogName = eventLog.GetPropertyValue("Logfile")?.ToString(),
                Source = eventLog.GetPropertyValue("SourceName")?.ToString(),
                EventCode = (UInt16?)eventLog.GetPropertyValue("EventCode") ?? 0,
                EventIdentifier = (uint?)eventLog.GetPropertyValue("EventIdentifier") ?? 0,
                EventType = eventLog.GetPropertyValue("Type")?.ToString(),
                RecordNumber = (uint?)eventLog.GetPropertyValue("RecordNumber") ?? 0,
                TimeGenerated = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(eventLog.GetPropertyValue("TimeGenerated")?.ToString()),
                TimeLogged = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(eventLog.GetPropertyValue("TimeWritten")?.ToString()),
                Message = eventLog.GetPropertyValue("Message")?.ToString(),
                InsertionStrings = (string[])eventLog.GetPropertyValue("InsertionStrings") ?? null,
                Data = (byte[])eventLog.GetPropertyValue("Data") ?? null,
            });
            inParams.Dispose();
            outParams.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return logEvents;
}   //BackupEventLogFilterBySource
```

Comment: Oh, very nice. Thank you! Although I see that your method just extracts the records from the event log. There's no way to have it save 'em in an `.evtx` file, is there? While doing my research I also found [ReadEventLog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363674(v=vs.85).aspx) function that can do similar stuff via PInvoke. But there seems to be no way to filter it into an .evtx file (aside from me doing it manually.)

Comment: Also just a side note on your code. I'd check objects returned by `GetPropertyValue` for `null` before casting them to string. In my case it throws an null-assert on some entries.

Comment: In fact I wasn't sure what kind of report you wanted. If you need the native format, I'll take a look at it. It's interesting anyway. It's strage though that you get an error for null values. Those are expected, but while debugging they have always been handled correctly, setting the property to null (of course you have to access those properties knowing that their value might be null). I'll look further into it.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, in my case `Message` property for some entries is returned as null and thus your code throws an exception. But it's no big deal. Just something to be aware of. Still, even if there's no way to filter it directly into an `.evtx` file your code lets me extract the relevant data. If push comes to shove I can always format it as an html file and present it that way. It may be even more user friendly than the built in event viewer :)

Comment: `DateTime` format is OK now, `Message` will be Empty if it's source is null. -- For what I gather, it's only possible to backup an entire (intact) log file. Creating a copy of it, that is (that's what you usually do). Log files are marked in a way that renders them unusable if not saved properly. It doesn't seem that there's a built-in mechanism to export a partial (valid) log. But I'll see if I can come up with something. Btw, your original code, without the `Sources` filter, creates a valid backup of a log file.

Comment: Yes, I know. The issue is that if I create a full backup the file is about 28MB in size on my machine. I can't expect an end-user of my software to be able to email it to me. (The entries I need is less than 1% of that.) But, you know, I'm actually working on a class to save it in HTML file. It's pretty easy to do once you have the data. So thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have to replace `sources` to `SourceName`. In order to get the right WMI query use `wbemtest`, it will exactly let you know which field to query.